# Android показать AppBar при инициализации

Tags: android

Запускаю програму, когда создается Activity первый раз сперва показывает само окно и после показывается AppBar, к примеру в Telegram при первом открытии Activity когда окно открывается виден AppBar. Как получить такой эффект?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У активити нужно задать тему с атрибутом:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

Указанный drawable будет отрисован еще до инициализации активити.

Т. е. то, что вы видите, скорей всего не App Bar, а некоторая статичная картинка-заглушка.

Примеры кода можно посмотреть здесь https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/